# How to implement \Phalcon\Mvc\Model::findIn()?

Tags: model, phalcon

Fairly simple question, but I can't seem to find anything about it.

I've got a set of ids, and I need to find all matching records.

So I'd like to query :

```php
$records = MyModel::findIn([1,2,3,4]);
```

But I don't know how to implement it. Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Criteria](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Mvc_Model_Criteria.html), in the `inWhere` method.

You could create a new model's method like:

```php
public static function findIn(array $identifiers)
{
    return self::query()
        ->inWhere('id', $identifiers)
        ->execute();
}
```

Comment: It works ! However, I get an error with inWhere when $identifiers = array()... I'm not sure how to simulate an empty result ?

Comment: I don't know if you need to simulate an empty result, if your $identifiers is empty just don't call Model::findIn

Comment: eg. `MyModel::findIn([1,2,3])->delete()`

Comment: It seems that creating a ResultSet takes a lot of arguments (see [phql doc](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/phql.html#using-raw-sql))

Ugly but efficient snippet :

`if (!$identifiers) $identifiers = array(null);`